# JS Framework with Rails Backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, javascript-framework

What JS framework is easy to get something up and running with rails on the backend? Is there a place that lists out the pros and cons of each? I know there's many frameworks and more and more keep being created, I just want to learn one that will be matured and won't have a radical change or update in the near future. So just looking for stability and ease of use.

Comment: Have you tried any of the "many frameworks"? If you're flexible about the Rails requirement, I'd recommend [Sails](http://sailsjs.org/) which derives from Rails and has garnered some positive reviews even from Rails lovers. I do not have a Rails background but haven't felt too limited by Sails.

Comment: I've heard about Sails but never looked into it. I've used Meteor and Angular, but I've heard the Ember or React I are really good. I'll take a look at Sails and see how it works.

Comment: Given that you've tried Meteor and Angular and are still asking this question, I would suggest making the choice based on the project at hand. There's no single choice that anyone can suggest in general. I would still recommend using Sails(with Angular, depending on your application's requirements) because its both simple and easy to customize. Sorry I couldn't find a decent generic comparison anywhere. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to learn and get good at a JS frontend that plays well with a Rails backend I would recommend reading into [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org), the docs on it are solid and its a fairly consistent frontend JS framework that can be really powerful if used well. But at the same time, with some basic JS knowledge, it's really digestible.

There is also [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com), which follows the Rails mindset of more convention over configuration, but it's more subject to change than Backbone or Angular.